# Append to hadoop sequence file

Tags: java, api, hadoop, sequencefile

Is there any java api to append sequence file in hdfs. I am able to write the file for the first time, but once i close the writer object and opening it again for appending some more data it is giving exception.

```
fileWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(fileContext, configuration, filePath, 
    Text.class, Text.class, 
    CompressionType.NONE, new DefaultCodec(), 
    new SequenceFile.Metadata(),
    EnumSet.of(CreateFlag.CREATE, CreateFlag.APPEND), 
    Options.CreateOpts.createParent()); 
fileWriter.append(something);
fileWriter.close();
```

Again opening the file writer for append more

```
fileWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(...);
```

then append more is not working

Comment: It would be great if you could should your code and the exception. However, Hadoop isn't intended to be used for file edits, so it's not clear why you'd need to do this

Comment: Edited the question,did you noticed

Comment: You changed two words. Please show a [mcve] of your code/attempts to solve the problem. For example, you can go to the JavaDoc yourself to search for methods

Comment: fileWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(fileContext, configuration, filePath, Text.class, Text.class,CompressionType.NONE, new DefaultCodec(), new SequenceFile.Metadata(),EnumSet.of(CreateFlag.CREATE, reateFlag.APPEND), Options.CreateOpts.createParent());   fileWriter.appned(somthing);fileWriter.close(); Again opening the file writer for append more fileWriter = SequenceFile.createWriter(...); then append more is not working.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include the exception you're getting?